# transforming from 'Y' or 'N' to bit

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table which has a column called Direct of type char(1).  It's values are either 'Y' or 'N' or NULL.  I am creating a view and I want the value to be transformed to either 0 or 1  of type bit.  Right now it's of type INT.  How do I go about doing this?

Following is the code:

```
CASE WHEN Direct = 'Y' THEN (SELECT 1)
WHEN Direct <> 'Y' THEN (SELECT 0) END AS DirectDebit
```

EDIT:  How can I make sure the column type is of type BIT?

Comment: Do you want NULL to be converted to 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will get you your bit..

```
CAST(CASE WHEN Direct = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS DirectDebit
```

Answer (score 4):

See if this works:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Direct = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: wow you're fast!  how can I make sure the column is of type bit?

Comment: bit (Transact-SQL): An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL. This way I think the values you get from the above query fit correctly in a column of type bit.

Comment: without casting/converting the response from CASE you cannot be sure of the type it will return

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE Direct
WHEN 'Y' THEN '1' 
WHEN 'N' THEN '0' 
ELSE '0'
END as DirectDebit
FROM TableName
```

... should work.